# Adding annotation from current location

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to add a annotation from the userlocation, when i tap a button. Its close to be working i guess, but when i tap the button, it will add a annotation some place in Africa. (latitude: 0, longitude: 0). Why won't it show the correct userlocation?

import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

@IBAction func addAnnotation(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let addPin = MKPointAnnotation()
    addPin.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    addPin.title = "Hello world"
    mapView.addAnnotation(addPin)

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you´re not getting the location for the user. You need to add a few things to your code to achieve this. I have added the entire code, check the comments for description.

```
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    // Add two variables to store lat and long
    var lat = 0.0
    var long = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Check if you have the right to get the location
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        // Start get the location on viewWillAppear
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    @IBAction func addAnnoation(sender: AnyObject) {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        // Set the annotation by the lat and long variables 
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        annotation.title = "User location"
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

    // To get the location for the user
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        lat = location.latitude
        long = location.longitude
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()


           // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
    }
```

You also need to open your `info.plist` file and add this attribute:
    `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and add a string why you need to get the user location (this is mandatory otherwise you will not be able to get the user location).