# User Location overrides Pin Annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

So I want my map to display both the users current location and the place they searched for.

Here's where there are some issues. Some times when the user searches, it will load the map with their current location, they place they searched for, and information about the place. Other times it will load their location, the place, and then it will show an annotation above their current location saying "Current Location"

[Here's a quick 10 second video showing that.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPuPtPpH8nY&feature=youtu.be)

I don't want it to show the current location annotation, but rather the place annotation all the time. Is there something I need to do in either the MapViewController.swift file?

Comment: Checkout my [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34863163/5576310) describing a similar question to yours and see if it helps you out.

Comment: @RashwanL I don't want it showing the current location annotation, just the marker. I want it to show the searched for place annotation all the time